# Problem with syncing 4 monotracks using pluraleyes and the R44's filestructure.

Tags: problems, plural-eyes

Hi everybody,

I'm on a documentary shoot and am using three transmitters with lavs and a boom, connected to a R44 multitrack recorder. I'm recording .WAV's.

The problem with syncing using pluraleyes is that the r44 puts all the audiofiles in a separate folder with each take. So now I end up with a lot of mono tracks with the same number (1 to 4)as their filename. Pluraleyes puts all of these on one FCP puts all of these on one timeline, so I foresee a problem.

Should I be recording to stereo tracks? Maybe use .BWF files to get more metadata?
Any tips?

Thanks.

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Hi Mark,
Couldn't you rename the files using a batchrename programme, based on the folder names or numbers? It would solve the identical names. Don't know how plural does it's work, but if naming conventions still are an issue, contact them or use their forums.
BTW I would always use BWF instead of wav.

Good luck

Comment: Great idea. I should have recorded a 4 track wavefile. Anyone else had a similar problem before?